# Visual Studio Code Terminal Exits Immediately

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I open the terminal in VS Code, the terminal opens for about half a second, crashes, and outputs this message:

```
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l, '" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

What could possibly be the cause of this problem. and how do I fix it? I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Is this the case? https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12602510/121655443-e88b0300-ca9e-11eb-88ab-6f79a81a22da.jpg

Comment: The terminal says "/bin/zsh: bad option: -," and the error message from VS Code is "The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l, '" terminated with exit code: 1."

Answer (score -3):

You would want to check your user settings first. Review `terminal.integrated` settings that could affect the launch.

- You're using a Mac, so on macOS, go to Code > Preferences > Settings. In the settings, you may want to search for this:

[image]

Just in case you modified `settings.json` without knowing, you could by typing in `@modified` or accessing it by Filter Settings (top right) > Modified.

If you **did not** modified anything, then it may be due to these:

> 1. Test your shell directly. Try running your designated integrated terminal shell outside VS Code from an external terminal or command prompt. Some terminal launch failures may be due to your shell installation and are not specific to VS Code. The exit codes displayed come from the shell and you may be able to diagnose shell issues by searching on the internet for the specific shell and exit code.

> 2. Use the most recent version of VS Code. Each VS Code monthly release has many updates and fixes and may include integrated terminal improvements. You can check your VS Code version via Help > About (on macOS Code > About Visual Studio Code). To find the latest version of VS Code, go to the VS Code release notes. You may also want to check that you have installed the latest version of your shell.

> 3. Use the most recent version of your shell. If your shell is installed separate from your platform, try installing the latest available version of the shell. The same advice applies if you are on an older build of your operating system. For example, some older versions of Windows 10 did not work well with the VS Code terminal.

> 4. Enable trace logging. You can enable trace logging and capture a log when launching the terminal. Logging often reveals what is wrong as all arguments used to create the terminal process/pty are recorded. Bad shell names, arguments, or environment variables can cause the terminal to not launch. Keep this log for later if your problem isn't solved.

#### Exit codes and shells

Search for the specific shells or exit codes in Google (if provided), maybe it would help.

If these still did not help, you may consider searching it in Google (mainly Stackoverflow or github).

Reference link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch